# Ruby 1.8.7 method parameter defaults

Tags: ruby

In ruby 1.8.7 I notice that

```
def some_method(arg1,arg2='default',arg3,arg4)
```

will return

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '='
```

It works fine in Ruby 1.9

However, this works in Ruby 1.8.7:

```
def some_method(arg1,arg2='default',arg3='default',arg4='default')
```

Is this normal, or did I do something wrong here?

Comment: Generally you have to place parameters with default values in the end. If you have parameter with default value, all next have to have default value too. I'm surprised that ruby 1.9+ doesn't follow this.

Comment: How would you call that ? `some_method(arg1, , arg3, arg4)` this errors out for me.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: just omit one: http://pastie.org/8044045. I personally think that it's confusing and ruby shouldn't allow this.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ah I see, this is very misleading and not very readable though.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The key here is unambiguity. As long as an expression is unambiguous, it is allowed in Ruby 1.9. Given `def some_method(arg1,arg2='default',arg3,arg4)` and you pass three arguments, there is no way to interpret it other than as `arg1`, `arg3`, `arg4` given. That is why it is allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby 1.8.7 only supports optional arguments at the end of the argument list.

```
# works in all versions of ruby
def foo(a, b=2)
  puts "a:#{a} b:#{b}"
end

foo(1)    # a:1 b:2
foo(2, 3) # a:2 b:3
```

However ruby 1.9+ supports optional arguments in any spot.

```
# works only in ruby 1.9+
def foo(a=1, b)
  puts "a:#{a} b:#{b}"
end

foo(5)    # a:1 b:5
foo(5, 6) # a:5 b:6
```

You're doing it right. Optional arguments that come before required arguments was a language feature introduced in ruby 1.9, and is unavailable in ruby 1.8.x versions.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I found some additional discussions about it here: http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/method-arguments-in-ruby/ -- Otherwise I have not found any great documentation of this.